# App is not running on iOS for latest version of react-native

Tags: react-native

**New project fail to build on iOS.**

Create new project with react-native init [Project Name]
then run using react-native run-ios, and got below issues on terminal,

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following commands produced analyzer issues:
>           Analyze /Volumes/mac\ data/react/UpdateVersion/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNodeList.c
>           Analyze /Volumes/mac\ data/react/UpdateVersion/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.c
>   (2 commands with analyzer issues)
>
> The following build commands failed:
>           PhaseScriptExecution Install\ Third\ Party /Volumes/mac\ data/react/UpdateVersion/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/double-conversion.build/Script-190EE32F1E6A43DE00A8543A.sh
>   (1 failure)
>
> Installing
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UpdateVersion.app An error
>   was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain,
>   code=2): Failed to install the requested application An application
>   bundle was not found at the provided path. Provide a valid path to the
>   desired application bundle. Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does
>   Not Exist
>
> Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UpdateVersion.app/Info.plist
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

**Other Information**

- React Native version: 0.46.4
- Platform: iOS
- Development Operating System: macOS Sierra 10.12.5
- Dev tools: Xcode 8.3.3

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I have done when I get these errors recently on iOS. Running these commands help me to remove the folder that is causing the problem.

```
rm -r ~/.rncache
```

Go this folder in your project directory.

```
cd /node_modules/react-native/third_party
```

Then download these files for the url.

```
https://github.com/google/glog/archive/v0.3.4.tar.gz
https://github.com/google/double-conversion/archive/v1.1.5.tar.gz
https://github.com/react-native-community/boost-for-react-native/releases/download/v1.63.0-0/boost_1_63_0.tar.gz
https://github.com/facebook/folly/archive/v2016.09.26.00.tar.gz
```

Now replace these files from the third party folder, clean the build in Xcode and run the code. If these steps lead to another error, do let me know as I have faced other issues after doing this. But, my problem was resolved in this manner.

Comment: i find the solution for it also . will elaborate it in moment

Comment: here is the error i got after these step you can find in the below link 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14382
and it given solution work for me

Comment: cannot find the ~/.rncache directory? I am on mac.