# React-Native (Build-Failed)

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile-application

I am trying to build a react native app but I seem to always run across the same problem that a lot of developers are facing at the moment. After creating the app

1. react-native init HelloWorld
2. cd HelloWorld
3. react-native run-ios (into the terminal)

an error such as this pops up and terminals the run:

```html
** BUILD FAILED **


The following commands produced analyzer issues:
 Analyze /Users/JemmaMarie/Documents/CareerCenter/Exercises/Ex_Files_Learning_React_Native/Exercise\ Files/Ch02/start/HelloWorld/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNodeList.c
 Analyze /Users/JemmaMarie/Documents/CareerCenter/Exercises/Ex_Files_Learning_React_Native/Exercise\ Files/Ch02/start/HelloWorld/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.c
(2 commands with analyzer issues)

The following build commands failed:
 PhaseScriptExecution Install\ Third\ Party /Users/JemmaMarie/Documents/CareerCenter/Exercises/Ex_Files_Learning_React_Native/Exercise\ Files/Ch02/start/HelloWorld/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/double-conversion.build/Script-190EE32F1E6A43DE00A8543A.sh
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloWorld.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloWorld.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

I have tried these solutions from stack overflow with no luck:
Environment:

node: 8.2.1
Watchman: 4.7.0
xcode: 8.3.3
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: unknown

1. Upgraded xCode
   Now version 8.3.2
2. upgraded react native and ran react native run-ios again
3. went to system preferences and selected the xcode version on the xcode IDE
4. ive removed node_modules to look for the "typo" that another had found and ran react-native run-ios but still does not work
5. tried removing the build folder ios/build by using rm -r  and ran react-native run-ios
6. tried another boilerplate create-react-native-app HelloWorld following the steps of https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

but get this error:

```html
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

Did anyone find a pretty solid solution so far?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this : npm install --save semver

Comment: this gives me the same error above ^. did installing semver work for you?

Answer (score 2):

I've met that error, I passed these steps and finally succeeded to build.

```
1) delete 'ios' and 'android' folder.
2) delete 'node_module'
3) npm i
4) react-native eject
5) react-native-git-upgrade  #this step is important
6) react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I've got the same error and I have posted my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408812/app-is-not-running-on-ios-for-latest-version-of-react-native/45413294#45413294).

Before trying out the solution, you should read the comments as they may be of some help to you.

Comment: thank you! dumb question though: did you drag the downloaded files in there or did you find that specific file that was originally in the third-party folder and replaced it?

Comment: yes , i have done that replacement in the files with download ones

Comment: okay, I dragged everything in but it gave me the same error. :(

Comment: yes, after I replaced the files in third party and removed the contents of build I faced the same error again.

Comment: I am sorry as it work for me , one other also , can you do it with ones again by deleting the node module and repeating the process again . Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much for trying! I really appreciate it. But I did try, but it didnt work either :/

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to skip the Xcode route and use a different boilerplate and its corresponding Expo App.

https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app

open the file on your favorite IDE

and run: *npm run ios* on your terminal

you are still able to use the Xcode simulator though. it should automatically open :)

thanks for the time and the input for my prior issue!

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar issue after having upgraded to watchman 4.7.0 using `brew`.

Looks like there's an issue in this new version of watchman:
[watchman issues 358](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/358).

At the end I solved my issue removing **the content** of the `/usr/local/var/run/watchman/` folder.